# How is WHS 2011 handling backups of a mirrored drive (RAID-1)?

Tags: backup, raid, windows-home-server

I have Windows Home Server 2011 automatically backing up my PC.
The relevant specifications are that my 500GB system drive is a software mirror and my PC is running Windows 7 Ultimate SP1.

I expected WHS to backup 500GB of data, but it is backing up 1TB of data. Here is an image of what's going on:

[image]

I would really like to know:

- If I had to restore from a backup, would I need to first setup
  another RAID-1 mirror?
- If I were to break the mirror while it's healthy, how would the
  backup feature react?